# How to reload current page when user click back button of browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Can i reload the current page when user click back button. I will give you a background of my problem to know the reason why I want to do this.
I have an asp.net web application 3.5 framework that display generated pdf file to an ajax modalpop. Doing this task is not easy as it was due to some cross browser issues that i've encounter and manage to handle all of those and only left me with this single problem. I manage to display pdf file on an iframe within the ajax modalpopup and this setup is compatible with Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but not on IE. I manage to found a solution on IE9 64bit using response.binarywrite and pdf file will display on a new instance of Adobe Acrobat Reader (v11 and v10) but on IE9 32bit this is not how it renders pdf, it renders on the current page itself and I don't want to be that way and when user click on the back button of the browser it will redirect to the last page visited not on the page where I click a button to display the pdf. I'm aware that by looking on the browser it still on the current page where the trigger to load the pdf happens. Now is it possible to reload the current page by clicking the back button and will it reload on the page where the pdf file is not visible. Refer to the code below to what I've done so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onunload = function {
     alert(document.URL);
     window.location = document.URL;
     window.history.go(-1);
  }
</script>
```

alert box prompt when I try to back on the browser but the code below does not execute, maybe it was executed but there is not effect on the page. Please I really need help thanks in advance.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4EJLG/show)

Comment: You can use History API http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html but I don't know if it work in IE.

Comment: @jcubic - IE 10 or above.

Comment: If you want to achieve the feature you want, then you might want to use the HTML5 History API. There also [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) available for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @Derek how can i use this on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SetCookie (name, value) {
var argv=SetCookie.arguments;
 var argc=SetCookie.arguments.length;
 var expires=(argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
 var path=(argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
 var domain=(argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
 var secure=(argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
 document.cookie=name+"="+escape(value)+
  ((expires==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+expires.toGMTString()))+
((path==null) ? "" : ("; path="+path))+
((domain==null) ? "" : ("; domain="+domain))+
((secure==true) ? "; secure" : "");
```

}

```
 function getCookie(c_name)
 {
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
{
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
}
if (c_start == -1)
{
    c_value = null;
}
else
{
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1)
    {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
 }   




 if (getCookie('first_load'))        
 {
if (getCookie('first_load')==true)
{
    window.location.reload(true); // force refresh page-liste
    SetCookie("first_load",false);
}
 }
  SetCookie("first_load",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand what you are trying to achieve but a possible solution would be to send the user initially to an html page that is there for the only purpose of rerouting the user to the desired page. When they click the back button it would bring them to this rerouting html page, essentially putting them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this technique ..

```js
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  var State = History.getState();
  //........ now use State variable 
});
```

Hope this will help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
<script>    
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
   window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
   history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
   location.reload();
});
</script>
```